# GLSL change pixel color of texture

Tags: glsl, textures, shader, pixel

I want to change a single pixel on a texture that I have attached to my shader.
There must be a simple function.

tex2D(sampler,uv) is for reading it out and returning that pixels color.
I need a function that manipulated that pixels color and writes it back on the texture.
That shouldn't be that difficult, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Why do you need to write back to the texture? Can't you just output the right color for your pixel on the fly in your fragment shader? If it's always at the same UV coordinates, it wouldn't cost much to do it.
Vertex and fragment shader aren't meant to write data, just to alter the rendering of opengl data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> That shouldn't be that difficult

Yes, it should be.

Arbitrarily writing to a texture is not a trivial or simple thing. Information flows in very specific directions in OpenGL: into shaders. The only outputs allowed from shaders are (usually) the actual shader output variables. That's how you write to the framebuffer, for example. Vertex/Geometry shader outputs can also be fed to transform feedback buffers.

Now, if you have GL 4.x-class hardware, you *can* write to images using [ARB_shader_image_load_store](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_image_load_store.txt) (which is core in GL 4.2). However, the minute you turn this on, you [take *full responsibility* for synchronizing access to memory](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model#Incoherent_memory_access).